# How can I check for collision against all components of the same class?

Tags: delphi

I have a small school project, of which I am required to create a simple game (platformer). I have been messing around with this which I found:

```
Var
 Overlay : Trect;
Begin
 If not intersectrect(Overlay, player.boundsrect, shape1.boundsrect) then
  //code
end;
```

This checks if the Player is colliding with shape1 and prevents falling past the shape.
My problem is that I am creating the shapes at run time in an array. I can't check for collision against each shape, especially if there are many and could be problematic checking multiple times every timer tick.

Can I somehow do something like this:

```
If not intersectrect(Overlay, player.boundsrect, arrayShapes[1..20]);
```

or create an event that only triggers when player collides with a component, then checks if that component is a shape?

If not, is there a better way to accomplish this without checking against each shape?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delphi custom animation - collision detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308077/delphi-custom-animation-collision-detection)

Comment: Animation using controls for sprites is a performance nightmare. Expect pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rectangle intersection is very simple function and there no problem to check some hundreds/thousands of intersections.

```
for i := Low(arrayShapes) to High(arrayShapes) do
  if IntersectRect(Overlay, player.boundsrect, arrayShapes[i]) then
      DoSomething
```

If you want more effective approach, consider using some spatial indexing structure like [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree). It allows to determine what rectangles are touched by given object without brute-force

Comment: Alright thanks for clearing that up, How can I check all the shapes existing in the whole array?

Comment: You could use a loop, @User.